# What is the difference between as="element()+" and as="element()*" in XSL?

Tags: xslt-2.0, xslt

What is the difference between using as="element(data)+" and as="element(data)*" in xsl:variable. The below XSL solution works if use "+" but not when i use "*". Can some one clarify.

Comment: Please explain for your second question what exactly happens when "the solution does not work". Do you get an error message from the XSLT processor? Which one exactly?

Comment: Updated the actual issue i am facing.

Comment: Break up the problem into several smaller ones and ask separate questions. Define the task completely: complete XML document (but the minimal possible), complete XSLT stylesheet (but the minimal possible), a full description of what the transformation must produce and how the output is related to the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
element(data)+
```

means a sequence of *one or more* `data` elements. That is, the sequence cannot be empty.

```
element(data)*
```

means a sequence of *zero or more* `data elements. That is, the sequence *can* be empty.